# How to configure Far Manager home directory?

Tags: far-manager

Far is great to work in Windows environment. But only one annoys me: when I do `cd ~` in Far console I get into `C:\Program Files\Far Manager`

How it can be configured ? <kbd>F9</kbd> Options & Google Search didn't provide any information

Comment: Did you try their [forum](http://enforum.farmanager.com/)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Admittedly, I had to peek around the sources to find the answer. Go to **Menu (F9)** → **Options** → **Command line settings** and change the **Use home dir** setting to your liking. The default setting is `%FARHOME%`, which is `far`'s home directory. So, for example, if you want behaviour like *nix, where `cd ~` changes the directory to the current user's home directory, use `%USERPROFILE%`.

*Disclaimer:* This option being more or less undocumented, I don't know if it has any side effects.

[image]

Comment: This works for me, but every time I restart the computer, the home directory is back to `%FARHOME%`.  Is there any way to make the new directory more persistent?

Comment: @AmadouKone That would only make sense if you've got *Menu (F9) → Options → System Settings → Auto save setup* disabled. Either enable that or use *Menu (F9) → Options → Save setup* manually.