# Far Manager: configure startup directories

Tags: far-manager

I can't find how to configure startup directories in Far Manager.
For example, when starting Far, I want to see the root of disk C on the left panel and the root of disk D on the right panel, not the %FARHOME%.
I'll appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Far Manager home directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1063168/how-to-configure-far-manager-home-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- start Far
- configure the folders as you wish, for e.g.

  - go to root folder of C drive in the left panel
  - go to root folder of D drive in the right panel
- **press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to save setup** (<kbd>F9</kbd>->`Options`->`Save setup`)
- check by starting a new Far instance.

Comment: Thank you very much!